flutter textfield restore last value
I have an error with flutter text field , lets say I have a list of models , each one will be responsible on showing a text field on the screen ,
List<MyModel>
so after using this list to showing a text fields and adding some text inside each text field and lets say 1,2,3,4
when I try to remove the model at index 1 with represent the text field that holds the value of 2 in the ui ,
it is removed correctly from the list but on the ui all text fields updates their state so that the shows values will be 1,2,3 not as expected 1,3,4,
I think the problem in the render tree , it keeps its sequence and just removes the last item in the tree,
I've tried to give each text field a key , in this case it work fine but the state for the item will be lost 1,null,null
my question is how to make the widget tree reflect these changes correctly.
here is an image for the showing of text fields

and this is the state for all three columns
class SsrTableState extends ChangeNotifier {
  var cells = <TableRow>[];

  removeAt(dynamic cardKey) {
    print(cells.map((e) => e.key).toList());
    print(cardKey);

    cells = cells.where((t) => t.key != cardKey).toList();
   
    print(cells.map((e) => e.key).toList());

    notifyListeners();
  }
}


I think the problem is in the element tree , when I remove the widget at index 2 , the  value restored from element tree is the same , so it will remain as it and jest remove the last element in the element tree

I don't know if you want to delete the model item where it has the number 2 -for example- or you want to delete the model at the index of 2 -for example- but I did both of them and use the one you need:
to remove an item from a list you have to use either:
listName.removeAt(index) to remove the item from the list at the specified index
or
listName.removeWhere((item) => condition)
Here is the code using them (since you didn't provide your code I made my own from scratch, you can edit yours as needed):
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // Define a list of MyModel
  List<MyModel> models = List.generate(
    4,
    (index) => MyModel(number: index, title: 'Title $index'),
  );

  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Model List'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Enter number to remove',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                int? numberToRemove = int.parse(_controller.text);
                //to remove the item on the index of numberToRemove:
                models.removeAt(numberToRemove);
                //to remove the model that have the number of numberToRemove:
                models.removeWhere((model) => model.number == numberToRemove);
            //  /\ choose one of the above methods and delete the other one /\
                _controller.clear();
              });
            },
            child: const Text('Remove Item'),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: models.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Model ${models[index].number}',
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      models[index].title = value;
                    },
                    controller: TextEditingController(text: models[index].title),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Model class with int and String
class MyModel {
  int number;
  String title;

  MyModel({required this.number, required this.title});
}

I hope that helps.

thanks a lot for your time, please just try to edit text field value and then delete one item from the list , you will see what I mean , current text field does not holds the current typed value and lost it

I have edited the textField, it was happening because we don't save what we type in the model item, so when we rebuild the UI the values will take the old model item data, hope that fixes your code
